# Выдача ключей по кругу

Tags: php, redis

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Ситуация:
Есть файл, в котором записаны сотни API_KEY (md5-хэш). Каждый с новой строки.
Есть функция, которая читает этот файл, и выдаёт следующий API_KEY. Если доходит до конца начинает с начала. Т.е. выдаёт API_KEY по кругу. Состояние (порядковый номер последнего выданного ключа) хранит в Redis (key-value хранилище). https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1867bb9b944511fe7960

Всё было радужно, пока одновременных вызовов функции не стало слишком много (несколько сот раз в секунду). В таких условиях состояние не успевает перезаписаться поверх старого, когда уже следующий запрос читает его. Кусок лога Redis: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1dfb63bfbf064d188dbd

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие существуют варианты решения подобного вопроса (крутить по кругу строки)? Возможно в виде демона или чего-то подобного.

Пожелания:

- лёгкость интеграции и взаимодействия с php;
- высокая производительность (способность выдерживать 1000 запросов в секунду);
- минимальное использование ресурсов сервера;

Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте делать не set и get, а increment.  Он [атомарен](http://redis.io/commands/INCR) и именно такой подход рекомендуется для счетчиков.
Учитывайте, что это работает только для чисел и может возникнуть переполнение в зависимости от разрядности системы. Контролируйте достижение верхней планки.
И находите реальный ключ массива путем остатка от деления на количество записей, чтобы реже возникала необходимость вызова неатомарных операций.

Answer (score 0):

> - высокая производительность (способность выдерживать 1000 запросов в секунду);
> - минимальное использование ресурсов сервера;

Просто держать этот список в оперативке, блокировать получателей, пока список не сдвинется. Можете попробовать через мемкэш, можете попробовать сделать демона, примитивный может и в сто строк уложиться.

**Обновление**

@universal_mind, блокировать должен не мемкэш, а приложение. Вот ответ на стековерфлоу конкретно по мемкэшу: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150287

Comment: Возможно у Вас есть ссылки, где бы про это можно было прочитать? Memcached не видел опции блокировки чтения.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку. Мне кажется, это получится одно на одно при большом количестве параллельних соединений.

Comment: @universal_mind вы имеете в виду, что там повторится ситуация с гонкой за ресурсами? В приведенном SO-ответе как раз дается пример атомарных операций, которые не позволят завладеть ресурсом двум скриптам одновременно.